# Convert a date with month number to date with month abbreviation?

Tags: r, date

If I have a date object in the format `2021-10-22`, how can I convert it to be `2021-OCT-22` in R?

Comment: `toupper(format(as.Date("2021-10-22"), "%Y-%b-%d"))`

Answer (score -1):

you could use month.abb() function

Comment: (1) `month.abb` is a vector, not a function. (2) How do you propose that be used given an input string of `"2021-10-22"` to end up with `"2021-OCT-22"`? While I don't know that this is an efficient way to do it, it is certainly *feasible*, but an answer has to have *functional code* and a mechanism to actually address the question; as it stands, this is just a comment to start the OP down a path with only a little guidance.